# ODBC fetch results from stored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, stored-procedures, odbc, fetch

I'm having a little trouble getting the results from a stored procedure call to an ODBC connection.

I'm not used to calling stored procedures through ODBC from PHP, and I find the documentation incomplete (or maybe i'm missing something).

The code below seems to be working. But I can't find a way to fetch the result from `$result`.

```
$connect = odbc_connect("dsn","user","password");

$statement = "storedprocedure('IN value','OUT value_1','OUT value_2')";

$result = odbc_exec ($connect,$statement);

odbc_close($connect);
```

If I `echo $result;` it passes me a "Ressource id#" so something seems to work. But I can't figure out the fetch part :)

Answer (score 0):

Your call worked and odbc returned you a resource ref from which you then need to fetch the results themselves: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php

Comment: I tried doing `$print = odbc_fetch_array ($result];` giving me an error "Warning: odbc_fetch_array(): No tuples available at this result index"

Comment: OK, so my assumption about that stored precedure were wrong. I should have realised that from the IN/OUT params. Not possible with odbc_exec. From the manual  If you need to call a stored procedure using INOUT or OUT parameters, the recommended workaround is to use a native extension for your database (for example, mssql for MS SQL Server, or oci8 for Oracle).

Comment: OK - I think I might have a little challenge here then. The source I'm calling via ODBC is Aspentech InfoPlus.21 - not sure there is and extension for that. Maybe ordinary SQL statements will be the solution then.

Comment: I don't know anything about that db and the way its stored procs work. Some dbs use OUT params and cursors to return data, others just need a SELECT or RETURN. Have a look at their documentation and see what options that db has for returns from stored procedures.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling across this thread... We ended up using ordinary SQL querys instead of stored procedures.. ODBC, IP21 and PHP was a bad cocktail.